# Android - how to handle user update when using two versions of the apk

Tags: android, apk

I currently have this setting in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

and it works for all users. But now I need to enable Google cloud messaging which requires minSdkVersion="8" so I am considering just making one version for versions less than 8, and aim the rest of the app to the versions 8 and up.

Is it enough to just have 2 apks, one of which has

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

and the other apk which would have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Is that essentially all I need to do? Or is there something else that needs to be configured? And I am assuming the android:targetSdkVersion="16" should be changed to 7 for the version targeting the older versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the GCM documentation:

```
GCM requires Android 2.2 or later, so if your application cannot work without GCM, 
add the following line, where xx is the latest target SDK version:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="xx"/>
```

that means you can add a minSdkVersion lover than 8, GCM will just not work on these devices. of course you need to check the SDK version in the code and skip everything that is related to GCM. in that case there is no need for having 2 different APKs.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason I am able to get it to work if I have this line <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/> but not this line: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/> ....am I missing something? In my phone the version I am testing with is 10.

Comment: @oh I think I am getting it - I SHOULD have it as <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>  ....but what I was worried about is that the app will stop working for people who have less than version 8 - am I wrong in that? Will it still work for those people and be compatible with those devices?

Comment: The problem I am having is that I wanted to leave the min version at 4 so all devices are not compatible. But when that happens, even my own device which is version 10 had that code not work.

Comment: i have just tried it in a small sampel project with android:minSdkVersion="4" and that works fine on my galaxy nexus as well as on the emulator with SDK version 7. of course you can not have any calls to the GCM library. check the version with if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) and exclude any GCM calls for versions < 8

Answer (score 1):

I would change the target of the lower one to 7, though I'm not sure it's actually necessary.

You will also need to ensure that the versionCode of the APK for SDK 8+ is higher than the versionCode of the other one.

Finally, you'll have to be in advanced mode of your APK files section on the console.